# "error: int cannot be dereferenced" while trying to subtract 1 from array.length

Tags: java, compiler-errors, int

Working on a word search program (not relevant to problem) and i stumbled across this error ("error: int cannot be dereferenced") while trying to debug.

```
                if((wordList[currentWord][0] == board[r][c])&(wordList[currentWord][currentWord.length(-1)] == board[r][c-1])) //second letter up
            {
                System.out.println(wordList[currentWord][1]);
                foundRow = r;
                foundColumn = c;
                return true;
            }
```

after trying to compile, i receive: "error: int cannot be dereferenced" . I've tried doing some research on this error, but all i could find was information on trying to check equivalence between this method and a normal integer, not trying to preform math function. Thank you in advance

Comment: `currentWord` is an `int`. It doesn't have a `length` method. What index are you trying to get when you say `currentWord.length(-1)`?

Comment: in my word search program, i've been having problems with duplicate letters found in the word search board. to fix this, i am trying to implement these if statements to guarantee that not only the first letter is a "match," but the second character of each word is a match as well "that way if i'm trying to spell apple, and there are two a's in the board, the first a that does not have a "p" in proximity will not be chosen as the origin of the word). Hope that explains my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Length is a property, not a method. It should be like so:</strike>

```
currentWord.length-1
```

Edit: from how you're using currentWord, it appears to be an int, and ints do not have lengths. This may be what you are trying to do:

```
currentWord-1
```

Comment: the parenthesis were an attempt to fix the problem, i did not have them originally

Comment: Worked. Thank you. For some reason I thought I was modifying the array list by length and not index.